# Simple hashing algorithm

Tags: c, hashcode

TL;DR: The algorithm receives a string as input, allocate another string to be the final digest, and start working on them. For each char on the digest (a null character on a first moment), it XORs it with every character from the original string, also XORing it with a set of "random bytes" that are specified in the beginning of the code.

Here are some results:

> "000" = qpktluvsqpktluvs; "001" = bcygoiwnccxfohxn;
>
> "abc" = ayedeufryzdfftds; "cba" = cqgleoxlarrnfnvm;
>
> "aaaaa" = hingixcphingixcp; "aabaa" = aprndovlapgneovk;

Am I mathematically getting the full potential of the performance I'm using? How good would you say it is compared to other hashing algorithms? Thanks a lot for reading!
This is my first hashing algorithm. My goal is to be simple and performatic. How can I improve it?

```
#define HASH_LENGTH 16
char *hash(char *input){
    // Alphabet and length
    const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const int alphabetLen = sizeof(alphabet)/sizeof(char) - 1;

    // Randomization variables and length
    const char vars[] = {
        0xA6,
        0xC1,
        0x5E,
        0x31,
        0xF5,
        0x88,
        0xA1,
        0xE2
    };
    const int varsLen = sizeof(vars)/sizeof(char);

    // Digest (where the hash is made)
    char *digest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (HASH_LENGTH + 1));

    // Input length calculation
    int inputLen = 0;
    while(input[inputLen] != '\0') inputLen++;

    // Digest cleaning
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < HASH_LENGTH; i++){
        digest[i] = 0;  
    }

    // Hashing process
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < HASH_LENGTH; i++){
        // XORs digest[i] with vars[input[j]]
        for(j = 0; j < HASH_LENGTH; j++){
            digest[i] ^= vars[input[j % inputLen] % varsLen];
        }
        // XORs digest[i] with input[i] + vars[i]
        digest[i] ^= input[i % inputLen] + vars[i % varsLen];
    }

    // Translates digest to desired alphabet
    for(i = 0; i < HASH_LENGTH; i++){
        j = digest[i] > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        digest[i] = alphabet[digest[i] * j % alphabetLen];
    }
    // Finalizes digest string
    *(digest + HASH_LENGTH) = '\0';

    return digest;
}
```

This is how the function is called:

```
printf("%s", hash("foo"));
```

Comment: Please add some description of your hashing algorithm. You will loose a lot of potential reviewers if they have to infer that knowledge from the code. Also please edit the title to not ask for improvements because that applies basically to every question on this site. Just state what your code does.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've edited the post.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add some test code to demonstrate how the function is used? It would also help if the definition of HASH_LENGTH was shown.

Comment: Edited it! Thanks for the patience!

Comment: What is the purpose of this hash function? Is it for data structures like a hash map? Is it for cryptography? Is it for something else?

Comment: It is intended for hash mapping but it's more a test than anything else

Comment: If you call the function like you propose, the memory allocated inside the function is leaked, making that a very bad example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not particularly familiar with C, but I have a few observations that may be helpful.

I like the attention to zeroing out your digest before you start. Using uninitialised memory is the sort of bug that can go unnoticed for a while, and it's good that you've caught it.

At the same time, I'm slightly alarmed that you're doing everything with raw loops, instead of using standard library functionality that does the same job. For example your loop to find `inputLen` could be replaced by a call to something like `strlen` and your loop to zero the array with a call to `memset`. As well as generally being more confident that you're using a tested and optimised routine, using library functions makes it easier to read and reason about your code.

I also quite like your use of comments. They're well placed, complementing the code and explaining some of the whys where the code explains the hows.

---

As for the hashing itself, I'm sure that the output looks fairly random, but it's actually doing a lot of work for the level of hashing that it supplies.

My top concerns:

1. If the input is longer than `HASH_LENGTH`, the latter part of the input is completely ignored.
2. XOR is a standard building block for this sort of low level stuff, but one of the key properties of XOR is that it undoes its own work. That is to say, because your `for` loop with `j` is *only* doing XOR it will confuse rather less than you'd expect for the work that goes into a nested loop.
3. The space allocated to `digest` at the end is underused. For example, because it's restricted to that alphabet, the first three bits of every byte will be "011". That has implications for use with, say, hash maps because the hash map will allocate 87.5% of its slots to values this hash function can never fill for any possible input.

Comment: I kinda tried to do everything from scratch, without many external libraries, just for studying. Thanks a lot for the helpful review. Now about your concerns, the "longer than HASH_LENGTH" was actually a bug I didn't notice. The inner loop is supposed to do `inputLen` iterations. Thanks for pointing that out. About the alphabet, what would you suggest to solve this problem? And do you have any suggestions on the XOR thing? Would mixing other operations in be of any help? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, mixing in other operations would help.

Comment: As for the alphabet thing, the standard option is to separate out the hash calculation (which should be a nice even spread across all bits) from the conversion to something visible for debugging. When you do the visible thing, standard is to use something like Hex that can represent all the bits of the hash. But when you use the hash internally, you keep it raw.

Comment: If you're wondering which operations to mix in, it's worth noting that "Add-Rotate-Xor" is a common design for hash functions.

Answer (score 10):

We really need to start by defining the kind of hash function we've created - this doesn't appear to be a useful cryptographic (one-way) hash function, yet creating strings as output seems to be a poor choice for hashes used for performance purposes (as keys in unordered maps and sets, for example).  What is the intended problem domain here?

We have a very low density of outputs.  On a system with 8-bit `char`, we use only .000000000000013% (significantly less than one quadrillionth) of the available 16-byte results.  That's very inefficient use of storage.

---

Should the function be allowed to modify the contents of `input`?  If not, then it should be declared as `char const*`.

---

Since we return a pointer to allocated memory, the documentation needs to be much more clear that it's the caller's responsibility to call `free()` when it's no longer required.

---

`alphabet` and `vars` can be shared across all invocations, so should be declared `static`.

---

All these values are potentially out of range of `char`, as `CHAR_MAX` may be as low as 127:

> ```
> const char vars[] = {
>     0xA6,
>     0xC1,
>     0x5E,
>     0x31,
>     0xF5,
>     0x88,
>     0xA1,
>     0xE2
> };
> ```

Use a type with a guaranteed large enough range, such as `int` or `unsigned char`.  How were these constants generated?  It's worth a comment explaining how these improve the algorithm, because it's not obvious to a casual reader.

---

If we declare `malloc()` before we use it, we won't need to cast its result:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *digest = malloc(HASH_LENGTH + 1));
```

Note that `sizeof (char)` cannot be other than 1, since `sizeof` works in units of `char`.

---

`malloc()` will return a null pointer when it fails - we mustn't dereference the result until we know it's a valid pointer.

---

> ```
> // Input length calculation
> int inputLen = 0;
> while(input[inputLen] != '\0') inputLen++;
> ```

This is exactly what `strlen()` (in `<string.h>`) is for:

```
size_t const inputLen = strlen(input);
```

BTW, it's probably worth using `size_t` (or at least unsigned types) for `HASH_LENGTH` and `varLen`, too, and for the indexing iterators `i` and `j`.

---

> ```
> int i;
> for(i = 0; i < HASH_LENGTH; i++){
>     digest[i] = 0;  
> }
> ```

`<string.h>` also contains `memset()` - don't reimplement it yourself.  Your compiler *may* be smart enough to spot the pattern and convert it to more efficient form (e.g. writing in units of your processor's word size), but even if it does, you've obscured what's happening here, and programmer time is much more expensive than CPU time.

---

The XOR loops don't seem to consider any of the input string after the first `HASH_LENGTH` characters.  That means you'll get lots of collisions for strings sharing a common prefix.

The nested loops mean we're doing much more work than traditional hash functions, which examine each input character just once (and are O(*n*) in the length of input).

---

Hashing the empty string gives undefined behaviour, because `inputLen` is then zero, and `% 0` is undefined.  That's a serious bug.

---

> ```
> digest[i] > 0
> ```

On systems where `char` is an unsigned type, this may be true much more often than on those where it's signed - that looks like a bug.  Reading on, it appears that you're just using this to implement your own `abs()`; don't do that - include `<math.h>` instead.

---

> ```
>     digest[i] = alphabet[digest[i] * j % alphabetLen];
> ```

That will give you a non-uniform distribution, unless you can somehow arrange for `alphabetLen` to be an exact factor of `UCHAR_MAX`.

---

> ```
> *(digest + HASH_LENGTH)
> ```

That's a convoluted way to write `digest[HASH_LENGTH]` - why are you going to such lengths to make the code hard to read?

Comment: I read somewhere that casting `malloc()`s to pointer types was a good practice, I'm not sure why, though. Thanks a lot for the helpful review. Just one question: why did you say I was reimplementing `memset()` less efficiently? How'd you reimplement it in a better way?

Comment: You don't reimplement `memset()` - trust your compiler to have much better knowledge of the target architecture than we C programmers ever can.  Each compiler can provide an implementation carefully targeted at its platform; portable code will not (and should not) do that.

Comment: But doesn't `memset()` belong to `<string.h>`? Do these libraries vary from compiler to compiler? I thought they were components of the language itself.

Comment: Yes, `<string.h>` is part of the Standard Library, and therefore supplied as part of your compiler.  That means that it's provided as part of your development platform, and implementations do indeed vary.  In particular, compilers are allowed to recognise Standard Library functions and handle them specially - for instance, see the [so] question, _[Can `printf` get replaced by `puts` automatically in a C program?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25816659/4850040)_

Comment: Minor: "This is exactly what strlen() (in <string.h>) is for: `int const inputLen = strlen(input);`" --> except `strlen()` returns `size_t`.  OP's code should be adjusted for that.

Comment: @chux, I realised that just after I went to bed; forgot to come back and fix it.  Thanks for prodding me!

Answer (score 3):

Review of OP's post and [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237115/29485).

**Bug**

`digest[i] ^= vars[input[j] % varsLen];` is *undefined behavior*, UB, when `input[j] < 0`.

**Bug**

`hash("")` attempts `% 0` with`digest[i] ^= input[i % inputLen] + vars[i % varsLen];`

**Failure on long strings**

`strlen(input);` can exceed `INT_MAX`. `size_t const inputLen = strlen(input); size_t i, j;` is better.

**`abs()` not really needed**

`char *digest` as `unsigned char *digest` would negate the need for `abs()` in `abs(digest[i])`

**Fundamental issues as code uses `char` rather than `unsigned char`**

Using `unsigned char` rather than `char` would improve hash quality and maybe speed over when `char` is signed.

`char vars[] = { 0xA6, ...` remains problematic as when `char` is signed, conversion of an out-of-range value to char is implementation defined and may not perform as desired. Simplify all this potential signed hashing with `unsigned char`.   The return type can remain `char *`.

Note that the C library functions perform internally as if `char` was `unsigned char` even when `char` is signed.

**Simplification**

`char *digest = malloc(HASH_LENGTH + 1);  memset(digest, 0, HASH_LENGTH);  ...digest[HASH_LENGTH] = '\0';` can be replaced with `char *digest = calloc(HASH_LENGTH + 1, sizeof *digest);`